# How to create a color break in a continuous color scale for ComplexHeatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to create a heatmap with the ComplexHeatmap package where I have a continuous color scale up to a certain threshold and a distinkt color for values above the threshold. I have tried replacing the values above the threshold with the maximum value. This gives me the desired outcome for the heatmap. However in that case my color scale legend is not accurate anymore. Is there a way to create a color break for complex heatmaps like "breaks()" does for heatmap.2?
Furthermore, can I include the na_col value in my legend?

For adding NA-colors, I tried adding an extra legend:

```
draw(myHeatmap)
NA_leg<-Legend(at = c(1), title = "", legend_gp = gpar(fill = "grey"), labels = c("NA"))
draw(NA_leg, x = unit(20, "cm"), y = unit(10, "cm"))
```

However it does not stay in the right position when zooming or exporting the image. Is there a way to fixate the position relative to the heatmap?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post the code that you have so far, and also some data for us to run code with. Look into the `dput` function for posting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I checked, that I do not have any values between (-)0.8 and (-)0.8001 and changed my colors with the col_fun argument of Heatmap().

```
col_fun<-colorRamp2(c(-0.8001,-0.8,0,0.8,0.8001), c("darkblue","skyblue","white", "brown1", "darkred"))

Heatmap(matrix, show_row_dend = F, show_column_dend = F, na_col = "grey", cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F,
               show_row_names = F, show_column_names = F, cluster_row_slices = F, cluster_column_slices = F,
               heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "legend", at = c(-1,-.5, 0, 0.5, 1), 
                                           labels = c("<-0.8","" ,"0","", ">0.8")), column_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10), row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10), col = col_fun)
```

For the problem of including NAs in the legend I used "annotation_legend_list" in the draw function:

```
myHeatmap<-Heatmap(matrix, col = col_fun, show_heatmap_legend = F, show_row_dend = F, show_column_dend = F, na_col = "grey", cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F,
               show_row_names = F, show_column_names = F, cluster_row_slices = F, cluster_column_slices = F,
                column_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10), row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))

#create legend
main_leg<-Legend(at = c(-1,-.5, 0, 0.5, 1), col_fun =  col_fun, title = "my_title",
                   labels = c(expression("" <= -0.8),"" ,"0","", expression("">=0.8)), title_position = "leftcenter-rot")
NA_leg<-Legend(at = c(1), title = " ", legend_gp = gpar(fill = "grey"), labels = c("NA"), title_position = "leftcenter-rot")

draw(myHeatmap, column_title = "my Title", annotation_legend_list = list(main_leg, NA_leg))
```